# Unable to pass variant data into shopify form

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I am trying to pass through variant JSON data using a data-variants attribute into an add to cart form, but i cant refactor correctly to work with Shopifys more up to date form syntax.

```
<form id="add-to-cart-form" action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-variants="{{variants_with_quantity_json | url_param_escape }}"></form>

{% form 'product', product, data-product-form: '', data-product-handle: product.handle, data-enable-history-state: 'true', id: "add-to-cart-form" %}
```

The data variant attribute simply outputs the object with no data in my version.
[image]

But i need the data to bee accessible on the form like so;

[image]

I am trying to add the invetory qty to the product.variants.json and need to figure out how {{ variants_with_quantity_json }} can be passed to the form.

```
{% assign variants_with_quantity_json = product.variants | json %}

{% unless variants_with_quantity_json contains 'inventory_quantity' %}
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% assign replace_hook_variant_id = '"id":' | append:variant.id %}
    {% assign replace_id_plus_inventory = replace_hook_variant_id | append: ',' | append: '"inventory_quantity":' |
    append: variant.inventory_quantity %}
    {% assign variants_with_quantity_json = variants_with_quantity_json | replace: replace_hook_variant_id,
      replace_id_plus_inventory  %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endunless %}
```

Comment: you need to post the error here for a better understand, codewise it looks okay

Comment: okay, are you use `form` HTML or `{% form%}` to show the `form` tag

Comment: I am using {% form %} instead of HTML version, the HTML version is a working scenrio based on a training program i am following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, you need to assign the data to a variable before pass it to `{% form %}` in Shopify
So you `{% form %}` look like this:

```
{% assign data_variants = variants_with_quantity_json | url_param_escape %}

{% form 'product', product, data-product-form: '', data-product-handle: product.handle, data-enable-history-state: 'true', id: "add-to-cart-form" data-variants: data_variants %}
```

or you may use the `{% capture %}` liquid code tag to get and pass the value

```
{% capture 'data_variants' %}variants_with_quantity_json | url_param_escape{% endcapture %}

{% form 'product', product, data-variants: data_variants %}
...
{% endform %}
```

[image: code image]

Comment: Thanks @onkar this help solved the issue, i can now see the data-variant info stored in the form. I used your assign trick but had to move the for variant in product.variants loop out of the snippet and place it directly into the product.form liquid file where the form is located. Thanks for your help!